# Is there a way to build Mathematical expression builder in RShiny

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

I am working on building a shiny app which would enable user to perform mathematical operations on the dataset fields.

Suppose my dataset has fields F1,F2,F3,F4,  my intention is to provide end user with ability to generate any mathematical equation using operators(+-/*,log,sin) on these fields.

For Ex : - F1 + log(F2) / F3* (F4). For convenience the user should have the ability to generate this equation with option of drag and drop ( on both operators and fields). Please refer to this link for more clarity on my requirement

https://support.formstack.com/customer/portal/articles/1882321-new-and-improved-calculation-builder

I have tried making use of shiny packages such as shinyjqui and shinyDND with no luck so far.

Comment: Can we see what you have tried? Even if it didnt work. Or are you looking for a starting point?

Comment: I am looking for starting point. I have done a bit of research and could see that there is a package shinyDND using which we can make any UI element drag and drop.For your reference :  https://github.com/ayayron/shinydnd/blob/master/inst/examples/app.R , I think if we can make this  element a field or a mathematical operator it can help greatly.